# How to match arbitrary characters inside [] groups?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am looking for all combinations for `foo` and `bar` no matter which order, which could run across multiple lines (in practice, no longer than 5 lines). Here is a test file:

```
$ cat test
foo
a
  bar
b
1 foo 2 bar 3
1 foo2bar 3




bar
a
  foo
b
1 bar 2 foo 3
1 bar2foo 3
```

**I am having trouble matching individual characters with newlines when using `pcregrep`.** I can match all individual characters just fine:

```
$ pcregrep --color -Mi '(foo.*bar)?(bar.*foo)?' test
test:1 foo 2 bar 3
test:1 foo2bar 3
test:1 bar 2 foo 3
test:1 bar2foo 3
$
```

However it can be seen that the multiline foo/bar combinations are not matched. Thus I try to match all characters `\.` and newlines `\n` but this is not returning any lines:

```
$ pcregrep --color -Mi '(foo[.\n]*bar)?(bar[.\n]*foo)?' *
$
```

In fact, I cannot seem to match and single character with the `.` operator at all in a `[]` group:

```
$ pcregrep --color -Mi '(foo[.]*bar)?(bar[.]*foo)?' *
$ pcregrep --color -Mi '(foo[\.]*bar)?(bar[\.]*foo)?' *
$
```

**How can I put the `.` operator inside a `[]` group?**

Answer (score 7):

The dot doesn't match newlines, what you can do is to use the singleline modifier `(?s)` that allows the dot to match newlines (or replace the dot with `[\s\S]`)

```
pcregrep --color -Mi '(?s)(foo.*?bar)?(bar.*?foo)?' test
```

or

```
pcregrep --color -Mi '(?s)(?|foo(.*?)bar|bar(.*?)foo)' test
```

or simply:

```
pcregrep --color -Mi '(?s)(foo.*?bar|bar.*?foo)' test
```

If you put a regex special character in a character class, it is seen as literal.

Comment: Thank you, +1 as this helps me at least resolve my current issue. `\s\S` is a nice trick, it works with other mutually exclusive groups as well, i.e. `\d\D`. However, I will wait to see if someone posts a way to explicitly match all characters in `[]` before selecting an answer. Thank you!