# Limiting results to ±5 lines

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am using the following regular expression to find instances of `foo` and `bar` in the same file which may be on different lines:

```
$ pcregrep --color -Mi '(foo[\d\D]*bar)?(bar[\d\D]*foo)?' *
```

**How might I limit this to having the words on ±5 lines?**

I am familiar with the `{0,5}` quantifier but I really don't see how to contrive the query. I was thinking about something ugly like so but I cannot seem to contrive it properly:

```
[\d\D](\n[\d\D]){0,5}
```

The above returns the following result:

```
pcregrep: Error in command-line regex at offset 26: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `[\d\D]` instead of `.`?

Comment: Try `foo([^\n]*\n?){0,4}bar` (untested). This should find `foo` and `bar` with up to 4 newlines and any amount of other characters between them. You should be able to adapt it to `bar...foo` easily.

Comment: Actually, it should be `foo([^\n]*\n?){0,4}[^\n]*bar` if bar isn't guaranteed to be at the start of a line.

Comment: @n.st: I was having issues with using `.`, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197071/how-to-match-arbitrary-characters-inside-groups). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
pcregrep -M '(foo.*(.*\n){0,4}.*?bar)?(bar.*(.*\n){0,4}.*?foo)?' filename
```

This would find lines containing `foo` and `bar` within 5 lines of each other.

EDIT: Adding an alternative as per comments:

```
pcregrep -M '(foo(\n*.*?){0,4}bar)?(bar(\n*.*?){0,4}foo)?' filename
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is matching [some spurious matches](http://pastebin.com/gjVqYF4i), such as the line with `b`.

Comment: @dotancohen What is spurious about the output?  Unless I'm missing something, it seems to do the expected.  The line with `b` is being produced because it falls between lines `foo` and `1 foo 2 bar 3`.  Similarly for the other case.  What did you expect?

Comment: I think that the term that I'm looking for is "ungreedy". The `bar` on line 3 should have "closed" the `foo` on line 1.

Comment: Thank you very much devnull! I'm still tweaking but I'm getting close enough to do what I need on the real data. If you have any sources for documentation on the regex syntax I would love a link. I'm finding that `.` is not working as I expect, and some other oddities that I cannot find documentation for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `pcregrep`, but this works on my (pcre-compliant) tests: `(foo(?:.*\n){0,5}bar)`.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not seem to work with `pcregrep`: http://pastebin.com/HyAmaSVF